# How do I specify a default in a rails 2.3 route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-routing

In my Rails 2.3.11 app, I want to specify that the default format for a route is :xml.  According to [the documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/routing.html#defining-defaults) I can do this using `:defaults`

```
map.connect '/myroute', :controller => 'mycontroller',
                        :action => 'myaction',
                        :defaults => {:format => :xml}
```

The documentation specifically says this should work:

> You can also define other defaults in a route by supplying a hash for
>   the :defaults option. This even applies to parameters that are not
>   explicitly defined elsewhere in the route.

But if I do that, then I get this error:

```
/Users/simon/myproject/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/routing/builder.rb:107:in `assign_route_options':
format: No matching segment exists; cannot assign default (ArgumentError)
```

I see that [a lighthouse ticket](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2478-defaults-not-in-path-cause-no-matching-segment-exists-error) has been raised about this; a respondent notes that it works for resources but not named routes; an admin has incorrectly marked it as fixed because he's tested it on resources.  Ho hum.

Elsewhere it is suggested that i do it like this:

```
map.connect '/myroute', :controller => 'mycontroller',
                        :action => 'myaction',
                        :format => :xml
```

but then if I test it

```
assert_generates '/myroute', :controller => 'mycontroller',
                             :action => 'myaction'
```

I get told that no route matches `:controller => 'mycontroller',  :action => 'myaction'` - I have to put the format in by hand, so it isn't a default.

How do I specify a default in a rails 2.3 route?  Do I need to get them to reopen the ticket and actually fix the bug?  Is there any hope that that will happen now Rails 3 is out?

Comment: 2-3-stable gets no patches, docs or otherwise https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/6501#issuecomment-5948321 It's sad.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm that is pretty weird. I've used :defaults hash in a named route, and it worked for me. Can you try using a named route instead and see if it works ?

```
map.myroute '/myroute', :controller => 'mycontroller',
                    :action => 'myaction',
                    :defaults => {:format => :xml}
```